# FIORI/UI5 Extension to standard NewsFeed application is not considered at the first call

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, feed

In the FIORI launchpad, after clicking a news tile I want the feeds to be displayed in a simple list with no links to the underlying feed. I therefore implemented an extension to the standard FIORI app AR_SRVC_NEWS where i changed the list mode of the "newsfeed"-element. I set a target mapping to the extension service in Launchpad Designer.

My problem is, the extension works well, but only on the second click on the news tile. The first click after logging in to the launchpad triggers a call for the original AR_SRVC_NEWS. Only after leaving the news feed and another click on the tile my extension ZAR_SRVC_NEWS service is called.

I noticed the source folder "AR_SRVC_NEWS" is already loaded on login to the launchpad. I got the feeling I need a plugin to the launchpad which loads my ZAR_SRVC_NEWS" instead but I´m kinda stuck here.

My extension code is placed in the 'onBeforeRendering' event handler. I´ve already tried putting it into "onInit" and "onAfterRendering" - No success.

Target mapping looks like this:

semantic object: 'NewsFeed';
action: 'displayNewsList';
Type: 'Ui5-app';
URL: '/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/zar_srvs_news/';
ID: 'WebContent.AR_SRVC_NEWSExtension'

Extension code looks like this (NewsTileDrillDownCustom.controller.js):

```
onBeforeRendering: function() {
    var newsList = this.getView().byId("newsList");
    newsList.setMode(sap.m.ListMode.None);
```

I´ve already tried putting my code into "onInit" and "onAfterRendering" - No success.

Any hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone faces a similar question.

I did not find a solution to make my extension work from the start. Instead I implemented a workaround.

I just copied every file of the original AR_SRVC_NEWS app from the SAP repository to a new UI5 app and changed the view according to my needs. Then I made the target mapping point to my new service URL and component ID.

Although I´d have prefered the extension as a leaner solution, clother to the SAP standard, this approach at least gets the job done.